# Intellij : Opening a project is stuck on loading forever

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nashorn, intellij-idea-2018

When I try to open a project, it keeps loading forever the file listing without giving a chance to do anything.

I tried to restart it, restart my machine and reinstall but couldn't solve the problem, please help!

[image]

Form intellij log, the following stack trace keep showing  :

```
    - @NotNull method com/intellij/lang/javascript/nashorn/library/NashornJSLibraryProvider$1.compute must not return null 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/intellij/lang/javascript/nashorn/library/NashornJSLibraryProvider$1.compute must not return null
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.nashorn.library.NashornJSLibraryProvider$1.$$$reportNull$$$0(NashornJSLibraryProvider.java)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.nashorn.library.NashornJSLibraryProvider$1.compute(NashornJSLibraryProvider.java:30)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.nashorn.library.NashornJSLibraryProvider$1.compute(NashornJSLibraryProvider.java:24)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.AtomicNotNullLazyValue.getValue(AtomicNotNullLazyValue.java:40)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.nashorn.library.NashornJSLibraryProvider.getPredefinedLibraries(NashornJSLibraryProvider.java:37)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.library.JSPredefinedLibraryProvider.getAllPredefinedLibraries(JSPredefinedLibraryProvider.java:88)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.library.JSPredefinedLibrariesData.create(JSPredefinedLibrariesData.java:109)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.library.JSLibraryManager.getPredefinedLibrariesData(JSLibraryManager.java:79)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.library.JSLibraryManager.initPredefinedLibraries(JSLibraryManager.java:29)
    at com.intellij.webcore.libraries.ScriptingLibraryManager.lambda$readLibraryTable$0(ScriptingLibraryManager.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:927)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:47)
    at com.intellij.webcore.libraries.ScriptingLibraryManager.readLibraryTable(ScriptingLibraryManager.java:71)
    at com.intellij.webcore.libraries.ScriptingLibraryManager.getScriptingLibraryTable(ScriptingLibraryManager.java:61)
    at com.intellij.webcore.libraries.ScriptingLibraryManager.getPredefinedLibraries(ScriptingLibraryManager.java:331)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.library.JSLibraryMappings.setMissingPredefinedLibraries(JSLibraryMappings.java:122)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.library.JSLibraryMappings.<init>(JSLibraryMappings.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor66.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:220)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:240)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:207)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:43)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.library.JSLibraryMappings.getInstance(JSLibraryMappings.java:158)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.library.JSLibraryManager.getLibraryMappings(JSLibraryManager.java:90)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.library.download.TypeScriptDefinitionFilesRootsProvider.getAdditionalProjectLibraries(TypeScriptDefinitionFilesRootsProvider.kt:55)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.RootIndex.buildRootInfo(RootIndex.java:196)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.RootIndex.<init>(RootIndex.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.DirectoryIndexImpl.getRootIndex(DirectoryIndexImpl.java:113)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.DirectoryIndexImpl.getInfoForFile(DirectoryIndexImpl.java:148)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.FileIndexBase.getInfoForFileOrDirectory(FileIndexBase.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectFileIndexImpl.isInSourceContent(ProjectFileIndexImpl.java:198)
    at com.intellij.compiler.backwardRefs.DirtyScopeHolder.a(DirtyScopeHolder.java:289)
    at com.intellij.compiler.backwardRefs.DirtyScopeHolder.access$500(DirtyScopeHolder.java:59)
    at com.intellij.compiler.backwardRefs.DirtyScopeHolder$3.a(DirtyScopeHolder.java:269)
    at com.intellij.compiler.backwardRefs.DirtyScopeHolder$3.fileCreated(DirtyScopeHolder.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:99)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.access$200(EventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher$2.invoke(EventDispatcher.java:79)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.fileCreated(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.BulkVirtualFileListenerAdapter.fireAfter(BulkVirtualFileListenerAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.BulkVirtualFileListenerAdapter.after(BulkVirtualFileListenerAdapter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor68.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:117)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:426)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpWaitingBuses(MessageBusImpl.java:387)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:376)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:357)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$2.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.after(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.processEvent(PersistentFSImpl.java:694)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.createChildFile(PersistentFSImpl.java:450)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualFileSystemEntry.createChildData(VirtualFileSystemEntry.java:217)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.StorageUtilKt$getOrCreateVirtualFile$$inlined$runUndoTransparentWriteAction$1$1.compute(actions.kt:70)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1022)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.StorageUtilKt$getOrCreateVirtualFile$$inlined$runUndoTransparentWriteAction$1.run(actions.kt:29)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.runUndoTransparentAction(CoreCommandProcessor.java:315)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.StorageUtilKt.getOrCreateVirtualFile(storageUtil.kt:140)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.FileBasedStorageKt.writeFile(FileBasedStorage.kt:186)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.FileBasedStorage$FileSaveSession.saveLocally(FileBasedStorage.kt:100)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.XmlElementStorage$XmlElementStorageSaveSession.save(XmlElementStorage.kt:137)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.FileBasedStorage$FileSaveSession.save(FileBasedStorage.kt:85)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImplKt.executeSave(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:542)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.doSave(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:282)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ProjectStoreImpl.doSave(ProjectStoreImpl.kt:316)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.save(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:172)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StoreUtil.save(StoreUtil.java:40)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.save(ProjectImpl.java:331)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.save(ProjectImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.NewProjectUtil.a(NewProjectUtil.java:187)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.NewProjectUtil.createFromWizard(NewProjectUtil.java:76)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.NewProjectUtil.createNewProject(NewProjectUtil.java:71)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.NewProjectAction.actionPerformed(NewProjectAction.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:301)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:307)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:291)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:528)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:48)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:548)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6548)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6313)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4903)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:786)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:723)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:395)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190826. You can try 2018.2 version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion where this issue was fixed. With the current version you cal also try (re)moving [IDE settings/plugins directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) and start IDE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You can try to Invalidate Caches / Restart from intellij.
2. You can try to increase memory assigned to intellij. Your project may need more memory than is assigned to the ide.
3. You can try to import some other similar project to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I tried that, but I still have the same issue, I just added the stack tares

Comment: Tried #1 above and that fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

Try going Help > Show Log in Explorer, opening idea.log in some text file viewer/editor, scrolling to the bottom, looking for error messages, and searching for keywords that might identify the cause. In my case, it was the Kotlin plugin (or maybe the Ktor and Android plugins that depend on it).